# How to use apollo-client API directly to query with fetchPolicy='cache-and-network'?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I want to utilize apollo cache with apollo-client api directly using fetchPolicy 'cache-and-network'. Seems that we have to use watchQuery api instead of query but unfortunately I couldn't make it work.

So could you guys please give me some example code to use 'watchQuery' to get data as what we get from 'query': loading, data, networkStatus...?

`client.query({
    query: Query.getUserById,
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    variables: { userId }
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data.loading, data.getUserById)
})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/) already  provide any configuration for all operation includes `fetch-policy` and it's documentation mostly cover all use case

Can you provide your code? i wonder why `Query` doesn't work when you using another type of `cache`

Comment: Just added some code for how I use apollo-client query directly.


For <Query> component from 'react-apollo', definitely it works well. But I couldn't use it in my component because it was called each time the render method run. So it was called so many times :(


Perhaps I already used it in a wrong way.

Comment: It's not that u used it in a wrong way. i think this is the bug which they solved it in `Query` Component
because I experienced this issue too when i set fetch-policy through @graphql() and solve it with `Query` component.
Have you tried to use async await ?.
You can try to use `refetch` i think it will work.
so you using renderProps, and passing `refetch` to your `component`. 
Or you can use apollo-hooks as well :)

Comment: I don't know how to use async await in this case. For using refetch, yes, it works well when I use graphql (from 'react-apollo) via HOC. But there is some problems:
1. that query will be called automatically when the component is created -> redundant query, I don't want to call that query here.
2. at that time, the variables of the query is not available, I have to pass some wrong data. Then if there are 2 different refetch queries and I call both of them, there will be some unexpected results here.

Comment: I see, try to read this post https://dev.to/bdbch/automatically-watch-queries-in-apollo-graphql-n45.

Comment: It works well as I expected. Thank you so much, Kaslie!

Comment: I am just finding the post hahaa, nice :)

Answer (score 1):

2021:

If you're using react, the `useQuery()` hook is already following behaviour of `watchQuery` instead of `query`. So you are allowed to do this:

```
  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(query, {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network"
  });
```

Or set it as defaultOptions when creating the apollo client:

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  HttpLink,
  DefaultOptions
} from "@apollo/client";

const defaultOptions: DefaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    errorPolicy: "ignore",
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
  }
};
export const platformClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: "https://xxxxx",
    credentials: "same-origin"
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions
});
```

---

**Some explanation on why `cache-and-network` is not allowed for `query` intentionally.**

The reason is explained back in 2019 here:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3130#issuecomment-478409066

Basically, the behaviour/logic of `query()` is not supporting this fetching strategy. So, they block it at typing level.